# Extrading Metadata of an audio streaming file (MediaElement)

Tags: windows-phone-7, metadata, audio-streaming, mediaelement, internet-radio

I just started to develop for the Windows Phone (7.1/8) platform and am still not really familiar with it.

My plan is an internet radio app which streams the audio file from a server. I used `MediaElement` to set the source property to the streaming URL.

It works and the app starts playing the music but I can't read any metadata about the song which is coming from the server such as artist name/title or any string which I can use to know about the song itself.

I've been searching around and tried the `MediaReached` event as well, but it never gets fired as well?

So any idea what should I do?

and My Code Behind Sample:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    MyMedia.Source = new Uri("MyURL");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hate to tell you this but it is because the MediaElement.Attributes are not supported for Windows Phone 7 - all the limitations can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426928(VS.95).aspx